# OpenSSL cannot verify opaque signed message with no content and with an attachment

Tags: outlook, openssl, smime, verifyerror

The sender has sent me an opaque signed message which has empty content except for an image as an attachment. If I try to verify this using command

```
$ openssl smime -verify -in testSmimeOpaqueSignedEmptyMessageWithAttachment.email -noverify -out testSmimeVerifiedOpaqueSignedMessageWithAttachment.email
```

It fails with error

```
Error reading S/MIME message
75769:error:0D0D20CC:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:no content type:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/asn1/asn_mime.c:379:
```

But if the sender sends me a opaque signed message which has the same attachment but there is some text in the message as well, the above verify command is successful and I get the decoded message back.

Is this normal? So if I'm using openssl I cannot have sender send me an empty message??
I'm using OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012 version.

Note that I don't need to verify certificate right now. Just the signature. And the sender outlook is set so that the message includes the sender's public certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my TextEdit was tampering with the message when I was saving email source from outlook into a text file. In the terminal using vi to copy paste the contents, seems to work with the verify.